# Android Floating action button grayed

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, floating-action-button

[image]
A grey color plus is appearing behind the floating action button.I have added colorAccent in styles.xml as blue.

Here is my layout xml code : 
One floating button. On click of that 3 action buttons expand.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/share_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/theme_floating_button_min_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/theme_floating_button_min_size"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:src="@drawable/send_icon"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/theme_fa_blue" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_to_list_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/theme_floating_button_min_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/theme_floating_button_min_size"
            android:layout_below="@id/share_btn"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:src="@drawable/add_to_list_fa_icon"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/theme_fa_blue" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/theme_floating_button_min_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/theme_floating_button_min_size"
            android:layout_below="@id/add_to_list_btn"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/theme_margin_small"
            android:src="@drawable/delete_fa_icon"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/theme_fa_blue" />

      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_menu_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/theme_floating_button_max_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/theme_floating_button_max_size"
            android:layout_below="@id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/theme_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/theme_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/theme_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/more_fa_icon"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/theme_fa_blue" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks artifacts from a stretched 9patch image, please provide the xml & the images used

Comment: i have updated the question .